# How do I install MySQLdb on my MacBook or is there a way I can skip install and use sqlalchemy without it?

Tags: macos, python, mysql

I have macOS Sierra and XAMPP installed (with mariadb as database).

However, on my local MacBook I am running this Python code to create table:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def create_db():
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    engine = create_engine("mysql://username:password@localhost/exchange_rate", echo = True)
    # Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
    # session = Session()
    # import pdb
    # pdb.set_trace()
    meta = MetaData()
    exchange_rate = Table(
        'inr_exchange_rate', meta, 
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True), 
        Column('as_of', Date), 
        Column('rate_per_usd', Float), 
        Column('last_modified', DateTime),
        )
    meta.create_all(engine)
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = get_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    if args.create_db:
        print("Create db called;")
        create_db()
        exit(0)
```

but I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exchange_rate.py", line 73, in <module>
    create_db()
  File "exchange_rate.py", line 50, in create_db
    engine = create_engine("mysql://username:password@localhost/exchange_rate", echo = True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 386, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 75, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 92, in dbapi
    return __import__('MySQLdb')
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

then I tried to follow instruction on the link given by @bmike:

```
$ sudo pip3 install MySQL-python
Collecting MySQL-python
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 490kB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-oxqg62fi/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-oxqg62fi/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-oxqg62fi/MySQL-python/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-oxqg62fi/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-oxqg62fi/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

but If I try to install config parser, I get its already installed message.

```
$ pip3 install ConfigParser
Requirement already satisfied: ConfigParser in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.0.2)
```

Comment: I sm trying to fix following instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14534571/3311276

Comment: You are going to LEARN A TON OF THINGS doing the install that way. If you get stuck and want a shorter path, I’d suggest https://stackoverflow.com/a/22513919/475228

Comment: What's the source of your python script and what do you want to achieve? BTW: Don't try to fix your problem with the answers in the linked instructions (and the possible duplicate there)!

Comment: I wrote script myself, I want to create a table before initiating the app.

Comment: If you are going to use pip3 / then you need to move off python2 - more reason to just uninstall everything, use homebrew to get the python you want side loaded, then work at pip first and then move on to using the DB once you’re sure you have a valid tool chain built up.

Answer (score 1):

To address the MySQLdb error - try reinstalling the package and then test just that.

```
sudo easy_install pip 
pip install MySQL-python
python -c "import MySQLdb"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22513919/475228

The above link would be if you can’t get this going - using homebrew to install MySQL helps with path and getting you set up with the proper environment / diagnostics and easy updating as the software gets patched over time. But, you don’t need that to reinstall the package that threw the error.

Also - be sure you choose python3 or python2 - it’s a bit of a hassle to mix them if you can even get that to work. If you are going to have both I’ll double down on using homebrew to manage things instead of using XAMPP.

Comment: AFAIR there is no pip for the system's default Python 2.7. Checking all other Python related questions added here by Ciasto, I believe there is a big mysql/python/???/?? mess on his MacBook and to answer his question(s) we need to know various env settings.

Comment: @klanomath yeah - it’s a mess - part is in python2 / part python3 - not sure I can help further and might need to step away

Comment: Pip doesn’t work, i have xamp installed at `/Application/XAMP/bin/` where mysql is installed. Mysql works i can start and use it but i cannot use mysqldb python connect engine

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz I’ve added the easy install to get pip rolling. I would suggest you make a new question just focusing on testing pip if you can’t follow the above. Then we can come back and look at pip - maybe with a second follow on question. This seems to be several layers of onion. The short answer is XAMP isn’t helping you out - you might have to choose a different install if you struggle to extend it.

Comment: @bmike thanks reinstalling just mariadb independently and getting rid of XAMP would be a long shot. I will give it a try but nowt atm.